# uploadify session problem

Tags: php, session, uploadify

Hello I'm using Uploadify to upload photos.
When user is logged, his *ID* is stored in session, but after uploading anything by Uploadify, his *ID* is deleted from session, so it looks like he is not logged in.

I tried to pass his *ID* with *session ID* and *session name* as **scriptData**, but it did not work either. When user is logged in and tries to upload sth, after upload session is clean (there is no *user ID* and *uploaded photo name* stored). 
When the user is not logged in, session contains *uploaded photo name*...

Here is the .js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fileUpload').uploadify({
        'uploader'      : '{/literal}{$PATH_TO_ROOT}{literal}scripts/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'        : '{/literal}{$URL_PREFIX}{$tc->get('uploadify')}{literal}',
        'scriptData'    : {'PHP_SESS_ID': '{/literal}{$sessionId}{literal}','PHP_SESS_NAME':'{/literal}{$sessionName}{literal}'{/literal}{if $user},'PHP_SESS_UZIV':'{$user->get('Id')}'{/if}{literal}},
        'cancelImg'     : '{/literal}{$PATH_TO_ROOT}{literal}scripts/js/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'fileDataName'  : 'Filedata',
        'fileExt'       : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
        'fileDesc'      : 'Image Files',
        'sizeLimit'     : 5242880, //  5x1024x1024 bytes        
        'auto'          : false,

        'buttonText'    : 'VYBERTE FOTKU',
        'buttonImg'     : '{/literal}{$PATH_TO_ROOT}{literal}scripts/js/uploadify/uploadify-butt-{/literal}{$lang}{literal}.jpg',
        'rollover'      : true,
        'width'         : 300,
        'height'        : 45,
        'hideButton'    : false,
        'method'        : 'post',
        'multi'         : false,

        'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
            window.location.href = '{/literal}{$URL_PREFIX}{$tc->get('photo-uploaded')}{literal}';
        }
      });
});
```

Here is the backend script:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $session_id = $_POST["PHP_SESS_ID"];
    $session_name = $_POST["PHP_SESS_NAME"];

    session_id($session_id);
    session_name($session_name);

    if (isset($_POST["PHP_SESS_UZIV"])) {
        $user_id = $_POST["PHP_SESS_UZIV"];
        $_SESSION['sess_us_id'] = $user_id;
    }

    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/img/';

    $newName = time() . '_' . StripAccent($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], '', false, false);

    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $newName;

    $savePic = savePic($targetPath, $newName, -590, -500, 100, $tempFile);
    $saveThumb = savePic($targetPath, getThumbName($newName), -185, -142, 100, $targetFile);

    $_SESSION['uploadedPhoto'] = $newName;  
}
```

Thanks for help

**EDIT:** Well I've found out this code works on one, but not the other server...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

in your code which display file upload button:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>

....

$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'formData'     : {
            'PHPSESSID': '<?=session_id()?>'
        },
        'buttonText'    : 'Upload',
        'displayData': 'speed',
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            ....
        }
    });
});
```

and on uploadify.php
just do this:

```
session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
```

and that's it, all session data will be accessible in uploadify.php.
Works for me.

Hope I helped someone.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, uploadify destroys the users session, but this fixes it nicely. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you using to generate this Javascript?

```
    'scriptData'    : {'PHP_SESS_ID': '{/literal}{$sessionId}{literal}','PHP_SESS_NAME':'{/literal}{$sessionName}{literal}'{/literal}{if $user},'PHP_SESS_UZIV':'{$user->get('Id')}'{/if}{literal}},
```

Is this being echoed out from PHP? Where is $sessionID, $user, $PATH_TO_ROOT etc... being defined?

Is there a session_start() executed somewhere before your sample upload handling code starts up? Without that, all your session manipulation will be gone when the script exits. You must call session_start() for PHP to preserve $_SESSSION for you.

Make sure that Uploadify is actually getting the proper session names/ID - if it's getting them wrong, then your code will reset the session id/name to something other than what the real session is, and you'll end up with the symptoms you have - vanishing upload data - because it went into some OTHER session.

As well, you don't seem to have ANY error handling in your script and assume the upload succeeded. At bare minimum you should have:

```
if ($_FILES['Filedata']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... process upload ...
} else {
   die("Upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['Filedata']['error']);
}
```

Just because the _FILES array isn't empty doesn't mean an upload succeeded. PHP will still fill in as much information as it can about the upload, INCLUDING the error code, which means there will ALWAYS be data in that array, regardless of the upload's success/failure.

Comment: Smarty templates, I've tried `start_session()`, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be testing this with Internet Explorer?

Comment: With FF4, latest Opera, latest Chrome

Answer (score 0):

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/

```
$('#file_upload).uploadify({
    // Your normal options here
    formData : { '<?php echo session_name();?>' : '<?php echo session_id();?>' }
});
```

In Uploadify:

```
//uploadify.php
$session_name = session_name();

if (!isset($_POST[$session_name])) {
    exit;
} else {
    session_id($_POST[$session_name]);
    session_start();
}
```